# Kernel not found and manjaro-chroot error

Tags: kernel, manjaro, kernel-panic

Today my laptop with manjaro stopped working and it shows kernel not found, then I tried to install them but after “sudo manjaro-chroot -a” command in live USB it shows

[image: error]